# Extracting keypoints from posenet to a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, pose-estimation

I am looking into the tensorflow implementation of posenet to do pose estimation in real time and also if possible in an offline mode. I am looking into the following repo :

> https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet

The keypoints are read out in the following function in the following section of code

```
    export function drawKeypoints(keypoints, minConfidence, ctx, scale = 1) {
  for (let i = 0; i < keypoints.length; i++) {
    const keypoint = keypoints[i];

    if (keypoint.score < minConfidence) {
      continue;
    }

    const {y, x} = keypoint.position;
    drawPoint(ctx, y * scale, x * scale, 3, color);
  }
}
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/posenet/demos/demo_util.js

I was looking into the possibility to extract the keypoints to a json file and if it was possible to do so ?

Any tips on this regard would be very helpful .