# TensorFlow Tensor to a TensorFlow.js tensor

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I was trying to take tensor from a ConvNet output and use it in another model in TF.js. Is there any way to save a TF tensor to a file ans load that file in TF.js and get the tensor back?

Comment: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.2/#loadModel

Comment: I have already loaded the model. But the input is a tensor in TF python, I want to use it in TF.js model. I somehow need to extract  32x32x32x32 tensor to TF.js tensor

Answer (score 1):

A tensor can be saved to a file. However,to load it back a server is required as the browser does not access the file system directly unless using an `input type file`.

To save a tensor to a file, the tensor values have to be downloaded first using `data` or `dataSync`.

```
const tensor = tf.tensor([1, 2])
// download values
const values = tensor.dataSync()
```

To see how you can save `values` to a file, you can use the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533698/extracting-keypoints-from-posenet-to-a-json-file/55558896#55558896)

To load back the tensor saved, the file content needs to be served by a server with an http request. Upon receiving the response of the request,

```
const tensorRetrieved = tf.tensor(contentHttpResponse) // if needed parse the string response using JSON.parse
```

The other option would be to use tensorflow.js on node. An http request and response would not be needed as node can access the file system.

Comment: I got the server, However i need a way to save a TensorFlow tensor from python to local disk then to server and from server to browser. However I am unable to save a tensor in python to local disk...